# How is a redirect response handled by the client using ASPX forms?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Regarding ASPX forms (and the AJAX control toolkit), what happens exactly, from the clients point of view, when a response is received from the server to redirect, like this:

```
25|pageRedirect||/path/to/somepage.aspx|
```

Does the client just simply trigger a GET for the url in the redirect instruction? Is there *anything* else going on besides the GET request, like tokens being updated etc.

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to manipulate an ASPX form programmatically (it's a search application). I'm sending a series of POST requests to the server that simulates a form button being clicked. For each request, a person and their details are added to the search. So, the server gets updated and sends back the ASP stuff in the response, including the updated VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION tokens, which I update ready for the next request (the next person to be added).

The responses I get back for each person I add are fine, they look normal, so I assume the server must be keeping track of all the updates correctly (I'm also using cookies for every request to keep track of the session).

The problem is when I'm finished adding people to the search and I try to actually perform the search. A final POST request is sent to the server (simulating the "Continue" button being clicked - sent to the same URL as for adding people), indicating that I want to perform the search. The response to this is the `pageRedirect` response mentioned above. Once I get that, I'm simply performing a GET to the redirect URL (with cookies), but something is wrong in the response. It's valid HTML for the page I would expect, but an expected identifier on the page has the value NULL and there's no search results when there should be.

I've examined the requests in Chromes debugger when done manually on the website, and they all match up with the requests I'm sending programmatically. I'm just mentioning all this for context, but my original question still stands. Although if anyone can provide any other insight into what might be going wrong, I'd appreciate it.

**Edit:**
Just to add to the above, I've used Charles to examine all of the requests involved in the process (headers, form values, message body etc.). I've captured and compared the requests made using a browser (which works) and the requests made using my application (which does not work). They are all exactly the same in every way (not including the token values and cookie session values) except for two things.

The application requests include the `cookie2: $version=1` header which I'm told is just a way of informing the server that the client is capable of working with the cookie2 spec. Also, Charles indicates that my application requests `Kept Alive` property is always false, even though I explicitly set the Connection header of all my requests to `keep-alive`. Are either of these issues significant enough to cause problems for an ASP server?

Answer (score 1):

My problem is not yet solved, but I think I have answered my original question, so it's only fair that I post the solution. When the redirect response is received from the server:

```
25|pageRedirect||/path/to/somepage.aspx|
```

...it appears that one of the ScriptResource.axd files that gets pulled from the server by the client (it says MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js in a comment in the file) contains some code for handling those ASP responses, specifically:

```
switch (a.type) {
...
...
case "pageRedirect":
    if (Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer) {
        var f = document.createElement("a");
        f.style.display = "none";
        f.attachEvent("onclick", A);
        f.href = a.content;
        document.body.appendChild(f);
        f.click();
        f.detachEvent("onclick", A);
        document.body.removeChild(f);

        function A(a) {
            a.cancelBubble = true
        }
    } else window.location.href = a.content; return;
    ...
    ...
```

So it is just a simple redirect with no other actions taken, from what I can tell. My problem seemed a bit specific, so I thought it might be better to try asking this question, which I thought might be an issue. Unfortunately, it hasn't helped me, but if anyone can offer any help for the problem I'm having, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question above starts off with a single fairly simple question. But then you provide a description of a whole bunch of other functionality and in trying to read through it all, I cannot quite determine what you are trying to get at. So, I'll try by just answering the single question you originally asked right at the top...

When you are speaking of "CLIENT" in your question, note that client can be anything. But for this we will keep it simple and say we are only talking about a user's browser. Also keep in mind that it does not matter what the development platform is. This is the same for all. If the RESPONSE is in reply to a page REQUEST from the browser, then the browser will process everything in the response. This starts with updating any cookies in the header of the response (which includes viewstate in ASP.NET WebForms). And it will also process the redirection directive in the response.

Where I think you may have some confusion is that if you have the browser making AJAX calls back to the server, the handler in your JavaScript code will receive the response back. The browser does not follow any directives included in the AJAX response. The browser is just playing host to the communication from your JavaScript to the server. If you do want that kind of behavior, then it is up to you to decode or parse the response you receive back and determine what to do with it.